# Problema eliminando espacios en blanco al final de un puntero tipo char*

Tags: c, string, punteros, c++11

Tengo un problema con esta función. Estoy intentando eliminar espacios en blanco al final de un puntero tipo char*.

Algo así:

```
char *ptr = "Soy un puntero dinámico y me sobran espacios al final       ";
```

Con la diferencia de que este es estático y el que yo estoy manejando es dinámico.

Estaba haciendo esta función para ello pero por algún motivo que no logro ver, el while no me está funcionando, es decir que el valor de c es **c=0;** cuando debería ser mayor.

```
char *quita_espacios_al_final(char **s)
{
    char *p = *s;
    if(p==NULL)return NULL;

    unsigned int i=strlen(p);
    unsigned int k=i;  


    unsigned int c=0;

    while( *(p+i)==' ' &&  i>0)
    {           
        i--;
        c++;
    }

    char *tmp = new char [k-c+1];

    for(unsigned int j=0; j<k-c; j++)
        *(tmp+j)=*(p+j);        

    delete [] p;
    return tmp;
}
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué no funciona? o ¿Otra alternativa para contar los espacios en blanco que hay al final de la cadena? 
PD: No me importa que sea en C o en C++ mientra funcione, pero el tipo no lo puedo cambiar, tiene que ser (char*).

Comment: No... no corrijas el código porque entonces se pierde la situación inicial y la respuesta deja de tener sentido. Si tienes muchas ganas de publicar la solución final hazlo pero como respuesta... aunque piensa que si marcas una respuesta como solución se entiende que siguiendo los pasos que ahí se detallan el problema se soluciona.

Comment: Ok, lo vuelvo a dejar como estaba!!

Comment: Si, lo comprendo. Ya está como al principio, simplemete he borrado el i--. Gracias @efeiron, Un Saludo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si suponemos una cadena tal que:

```
char *ptr = "hola  ";
```

Nos encontraremos con que

```
strlen(ptr) == 6
```

Y si miramos la ubicación de los diferentes elementos en memoria tenemos lo siguiente:

```
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06
  h    o    l    a    _    _   \0
```

Es decir, la posición `6` se corresponde con un caracter nulo.

Esto viene con motivo de la siguiente línea:

```
while( *(p+i)==' ' &&  i>0)
```

donde `i`, inicialmente, vale `strlen(p)`...

... prueba a restarle 1 a `i`:

```
unsigned int i=strlen(p);
if( i > 0 )
  i--;
```

Comment: Perfecto!! Funciona!! :-)  Muchas gracias @eferion!!